# conditional type define in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I need to define a template class A, which has a nested type according to nested type in template argument. Like this:

```
template<typename Container>
class A
{
public:
    using NestedType = if (Container has nested type Container::NestedTypeA)
    {
        Container::NestedTypeA;
    }
    else if (Container has nested type Container::NestedTypeB)
    {
        Container::NestedTypeB;
    }
    else
    {
        Container::NestedTypeC;
    }
};
```

How to implement this using declaration? Or is there another way to acheive the same effect?

---

Thanks the answers by 康桓瑋 and Jarod42. But the two answers both use C++20's concepts. How about use C++17 at most?

Comment: Pass the "nested type" as a second argument.

Comment: [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) with appropriate traits.

Comment: @Jarod42: That doesn’t let you name the nonexistent types in the “branches” not taken.  You have to put the names in the body of a SFINAE-d specialization.

Comment: @DavisHerring: with traits to delay instantiation, it might work (See my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++20, you can just use concepts

```
template<typename Container>
struct B { };

template<typename Container>
  requires requires { typename Container::NestedTypeA; } 
struct B<Container> {
  using NestedType = typename Container::NestedTypeA;
};

template<typename Container>
  requires requires { typename Container::NestedTypeB; } &&
         (!requires { typename Container::NestedTypeA; })
struct B<Container> {
  using NestedType = typename Container::NestedTypeB;
};

template<typename Container>
  requires requires { typename Container::NestedTypeC; } &&
         (!requires { typename Container::NestedTypeA; }) &&
         (!requires { typename Container::NestedTypeB; })
struct B<Container> {
  using NestedType = typename Container::NestedTypeC;
};

template<typename Container>
class A : public B<Container> {};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qhzrPesnr)

In C++17, you can use [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) to detect the validity of member types.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Container, typename = void>
constexpr bool HasNestedTypeA = false;
template<typename Container>
constexpr bool HasNestedTypeA<
  Container, std::void_t<typename Container::NestedTypeA>> = true;

template<typename Container, typename = void>
constexpr bool HasNestedTypeB = false;
template<typename Container>
constexpr bool HasNestedTypeB<
  Container, std::void_t<typename Container::NestedTypeB>> = true;

template<typename Container, typename = void>
constexpr bool HasNestedTypeC = false;
template<typename Container>
constexpr bool HasNestedTypeC<
  Container, std::void_t<typename Container::NestedTypeC>> = true;

template<
  typename Container, 
  bool = HasNestedTypeA<Container>,
  bool = HasNestedTypeB<Container>,
  bool = HasNestedTypeC<Container>>
struct B { };

template<typename Container>
struct B<Container, false, false, false> {};

template<typename Container, bool B1, bool B2>
struct B<Container, true, B1, B2> {
  using NestedType = typename Container::NestedTypeA;
};

template<typename Container, bool B1>
struct B<Container, false, true, B1> {
  using NestedType = typename Container::NestedTypeB;
};

template<typename Container>
struct B<Container, false, false, true> {
  using NestedType = typename Container::NestedTypeC;
};

template<typename Container>
class A : public B<Container> {};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P4PbsMx44)

Comment: THX. How to do this with C++17?

Answer (score 1):

With [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and appropriate traits, you might do something like:

```
template <typename Container>
struct NestedTypeA
{
    using type = typename Container::NestedTypeA;
};

template <typename Container>
struct NestedTypeB
{
    using type = typename Container::NestedTypeB;
};

template <typename Container>
struct NestedTypeC
{
    using type = typename Container::NestedTypeC;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool hasNestedTypeA = requires{ typename T::NestedTypeA; };

template <typename T>
constexpr bool hasNestedTypeB = requires{ typename T::NestedTypeB; };

template<typename Container>
class A
{
public:
    using NestedType = typename std::conditional_t<
                            hasNestedTypeA<Container>,
                            NestedTypeA<Container>,
                            std::conditional_t<hasNestedTypeB<Container>,
                                               NestedTypeB<Container>,
                                               NestedTypeC<Container>>
                        >::type;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Kzj9xaa7G)

Comment: This appears to have symmetry between `NestedTypeA` and `NestedTypeB`, the problem statement indicates a preference for `NestedTypeA`

Comment: @BenVoigt: Indeed, fixed with my initial idea with `std::conditional`.

Comment: THX. How to do this with C++17?

Comment: @byhc: Detecting subtype traits can be done with `std::void_t` and enabler instead of the C++20  `requires`: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nn49xcPGj).